# Why is my new SQL view/query ignoring my business rules?

Tags: sql, function, view, sql-server-2008-r2

This is a really complicated issue, for which I apologize in advance. I've been doing a lot of analysis and research on my issue, and I can't find any answers.

In case this is relevant, I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2.

I created a scalar value function that WORKS according to my business rules, but when used in a stored procedure takes 17 minutes to run. Also, it's all R.B.A.R. which is just annoying the heck out of me.

As a result, I'm trying to write a view to replace it. The view that I've written and joined to my stored procedure takes 7 seconds to run. The problem is that it's not obeying all the business rules.

I'll post both the original function, plus the new view, but first I'm going to try to explain the business rules before hand, because this whole thing is messy.

1. If a sale was completed, return "Completed".
2. If a sales number was NOT completed, but another sales person did complete the sale, Return "Saved".
3. If no sales person was able to complete the sale:

   a. and the customer cancelled the sale, Return "Cancelled"

   b. only one Sales person attempted to make the sale, Return "Missed"

   c. more than one Sales person attempted to make the sale, but both missed:

   i. if one of those sales people "owned" the customer account, make THEIR call number "missed" and any other associated call numbers "not missed"

   ii. if none of the sales people owned the customer account, add the "missed" to the sales person who received the order first.

Last note: each customer order/sale has a unifying "CallNumber", with a list of one or more "SalesNumbers", which are each an attempt by a Sales Person to fulfill the order.

Here's the function

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[FindMissedVsSaved]
```

(
    @SalesNumber  int,
    @SalesDate      nvarchar(10)
)
RETURNS nvarchar(20)
AS
BEGIN

```
DECLARE @Status AS nvarchar(20)

DECLARE @Year AS int
SET @Year = YEAR(@SalesDate)
```

-- This section is used to determine who the "owner" of the customer is; It is only used for Double misses

```
DECLARE @SalesPerson AS nvarchar(6)
DECLARE @SalesType AS int
SET @SalesType = (SELECT SalesType FROM MyDB.dbo.Calls WHERE SalesNumber=@SalesNumber AND SalesDate = @SalesDate)
SET @SalesPerson =
    CASE 
        WHEN @SalesType IN (8, 12) THEN 
            ISNULL((SELECT TOP (1) b.SalesPersonName From MyDB.dbo.Calls AS t
            JOIN MyDB.dbo.Call_Sources AS cs ON t.callsource = cs.code
            JOIN AccountAssignment AS csa ON cs.code = csa.MyDBAccountAssignmentID
            JOIN SalesPerson AS b ON csa.AssignedSalesPersonID = b.SalesPersonID
            WHERE t.SalesDate = @SalesDate AND t.SalesNumber = @SalesNumber), 'No Assigned Sales Person')
        WHEN @SalesType IN (9, 10, 13, 14) THEN
            ISNULL((SELECT TOP (1) b.SalesPersonName From MyDB.dbo.Calls AS t
            JOIN MyDB.dbo.Customer AS f ON t.ofac = f.code
            JOIN SalesPerson AS b ON f.MyDBSales_Person = b.MyDBSales_Person
            WHERE t.SalesDate = @SalesDate AND t.SalesNumber = @SalesNumber), 'No Assigned Sales Person')
        ELSE 'Error'
    END
DECLARE @MissedSalesPerson AS nvarchar(6)
SET @MissedSalesPerson = 
    (SELECT TOP (1) ui.SalesPersonID FROM MyDB.dbo.Calls AS t
    JOIN MyDB.dbo.Vehicle_Schedule AS vs On t.SchRecNo = vs.schrecno
    JOIN MyDB.dbo.SalesPeople AS ui ON vs.unit_code = ui.code
    WHERE t.SalesNumber=@SalesNumber AND t.SalesDate=@SalesDate)
```

-- Pulls the unique CallNumber for these records

```
DECLARE @CallNumber AS nvarchar(15)
SET @CallNumber = (
    SELECT TOP (1) CallNumber 
    FROM MyDB.dbo.Calls 
    WHERE SalesNumber = @SalesNumber 
    AND SalesDate = @SalesDate)
```

--Figures out IF the Sale was made and WHO made the sale

```
DECLARE @SavedSalesPerson AS nvarchar(8)
SET @SavedSalesPerson = (SELECT TOP (1) ui.SalesPersonID
--DISTINCT(ui.SalesPersonID )
            FROM MyDB.dbo.Calls AS t
            JOIN MyDB.dbo.Vehicle_Schedule AS vs ON t.SchRecNo = vs.schrecno
            JOIN MyDB.dbo.SalesPeople AS ui ON vs.unit_code = ui.code
            WHERE YEAR(SalesDate) = @Year 
            AND CallNumber=@CallNumber 
            AND SalesNumber <> @SalesNumber
            AND SaleMade = 7
            AND SalesType IN (8, 9, 10, 12, 13, 14))
```

--This final section sets the status to be returned for this particular SalesNumber

```
SET @Status = 
    CASE
        -- The Call Number passed in Made the sale
        WHEN EXISTS (SELECT TOP (1) SaleMade FROM MyDB.dbo.Calls
            WHERE YEAR(SalesDate) = @Year 
            AND CallNumber=@CallNumber 
            AND SalesNumber = @SalesNumber AND SaleMade = 7)
        THEN 'Completed'

        --The Call Number passed in did NOT make the sale but another sales person was able to accept the call but the customer cancelled
        WHEN EXISTS(SELECT TOP (1) CxlReason FROM MyDB.dbo.Calls
            WHERE YEAR(SalesDate) = @Year 
            AND CallNumber=@CallNumber 
            AND SalesNumber <> @SalesNumber 
            AND CxlReason IN (3, 6, 7, 8, 13, 27, 32, 33, 36, 37, 44, 46)
            AND SalesType IN (8, 9, 10, 12, 13, 14))
        THEN 'Cancelled' 

        --Another Sales Person made the sale  i.e. save
        WHEN EXISTS(
            SELECT TOP (1) ui.SalesPersonID 
            FROM MyDB.dbo.Calls AS t
            JOIN MyDB.dbo.Vehicle_Schedule AS vs ON t.SchRecNo = vs.schrecno
            JOIN MyDB.dbo.SalesPeople AS ui ON vs.unit_code = ui.code
            WHERE YEAR(SalesDate) = @Year 
            AND CallNumber=@CallNumber 
            AND SalesNumber <> @SalesNumber
            AND SaleMade = 7
            AND SalesType IN (8, 9, 10, 12, 13, 14)) 
        THEN 'Saved by ' + @SavedSalesPerson

        --When it has a MISC15 timestamp on it, but doesn't meet the saved criteria
        WHEN 
            (SELECT TOP (1) tmt.Misc15 
            FROM MyDB.dbo.Calls AS t
            LEFT OUTER JOIN MyDB.dbo.Trip_Misc_Times AS tmt ON t.SalesDate = tmt.SalesDate AND t.job = tmt.job
            WHERE t.SalesNumber = @SalesNumber AND YEAR(t.SalesDate) = @Year) IS NOT NULL
        THEN 'Other'

        --The miss should always go on the Sales Person who Owns the Customer Account, if they attempted the Sale
        WHEN @MissedSalesPerson = @SalesPerson THEN 'Missed'

        --For cases when this was the only sales person that attempted to make the sale and s/he was unable to complete it
        WHEN NOT EXISTS(SELECT TOP (1) ui.SalesPersonID 
            FROM MyDB.dbo.Calls AS t
            JOIN MyDB.dbo.Vehicle_Schedule AS vs ON t.SchRecNo = vs.schrecno
            JOIN MyDB.dbo.SalesPeople AS ui ON vs.unit_code = ui.code
            WHERE YEAR(SalesDate) = @Year 
                AND CallNumber=@CallNumber 
                AND SalesNumber <> @SalesNumber         
                AND SalesType IN (8, 9, 10, 12, 13, 14)) 
        THEN 'Missed'

        --Looking for another SalesPerson that might have attempted the Sale
        WHEN @MissedSalesPerson <> @SalesPerson AND @SalesPerson <> 'No Assigned Sales Person' THEN
            CASE
                --Another Sales Person attempted the transport and the Customer Cancelled
                WHEN                    
                    EXISTS(SELECT TOP (1) SalesNumber 
                        FROM MyDB.dbo.Calls
                        WHERE SalesDate=@SalesDate AND CallNumber = @CallNumber
                        AND SalesNumber <> @SalesNumber
                        AND cxlReason IN (3, 6, 7, 8, 13, 27, 32, 33, 36, 37, 46)
                        AND SalesType IN (8, 9, 10, 12, 13, 14))
                THEN 'Not Missed'

                --Owner Sales Person also attempted and missed
                WHEN                    
                    EXISTS(SELECT TOP (1) ui.SalesPersonID 
                        FROM MyDB.dbo.Calls AS t
                        JOIN MyDB.dbo.Vehicle_Schedule AS vs ON t.SchRecNo = vs.schrecno
                        JOIN MyDB.dbo.SalesPeople AS ui ON vs.unit_code = ui.code
                        WHERE YEAR(SalesDate) = @Year 
                            AND CallNumber=@CallNumber 
                            AND SalesNumber <> @SalesNumber
                            AND ui.SalesPersonID = @SalesPerson
                            AND SalesType IN (8, 9, 10, 12, 13, 14)) 
                THEN 'Not Missed'

                --Another Sales Person attempted the sale but the Sales Person for this Call was given the call first
                WHEN EXISTS(SELECT TOP (1) ui.SalesPersonID 
                        FROM MyDB.dbo.Calls AS t
                        JOIN MyDB.dbo.Vehicle_Schedule AS vs ON t.SchRecNo = vs.schrecno
                        JOIN MyDB.dbo.SalesPeople AS ui ON vs.unit_code = ui.code
                        WHERE YEAR(SalesDate) = @Year 
                            AND CallNumber=@CallNumber 
                            AND SalesNumber <> @SalesNumber
                            AND ui.SalesPersonID <> @SalesPerson
                            AND SalesType IN (8, 9, 10, 12, 13, 14)) 
                    AND @MissedSalesPerson = 
                        (SELECT Top (1) ui.SalesPersonID 
                        FROM MyDB.dbo.Calls AS t
                        Join MyDB.dbo.Vehicle_Schedule AS vs ON t.SchRecNo = vs.schrecno
                        JOIN MyDB.dbo.SalesPeople AS ui ON vs.unit_code = ui.code
                        WHERE t.SalesDate = @SalesDate 
                        AND t.CallNumber = @CallNumber
                        AND t.SalesType IN (8, 9, 10, 12, 13, 14)
                        ORDER BY t.calltime)
                THEN 'Missed'

                --Another Sales Person attempted the sale and the Sales Person for this Call/Transaction was NOT called first
                WHEN EXISTS(SELECT TOP (1) ui.SalesPersonID 
                        FROM MyDB.dbo.Calls AS t
                        JOIN MyDB.dbo.Vehicle_Schedule AS vs ON t.SchRecNo = vs.schrecno
                        JOIN MyDB.dbo.SalesPeople AS ui ON vs.unit_code = ui.code
                        WHERE YEAR(SalesDate) = @Year 
                            AND CallNumber=@CallNumber 
                            AND SalesNumber <> @SalesNumber
                            AND ui.SalesPersonID <> @SalesPerson
                            AND SalesType IN (8, 9, 10, 12, 13, 14)) 
                    AND @MissedSalesPerson <> 
                        (SELECT Top (1) ui.SalesPersonID 
                        FROM MyDB.dbo.Calls AS t
                        Join MyDB.dbo.Vehicle_Schedule AS vs ON t.SchRecNo = vs.schrecno
                        JOIN MyDB.dbo.SalesPeople AS ui ON vs.unit_code = ui.code
                        WHERE t.SalesDate = @SalesDate 
                        AND t.CallNumber = @CallNumber
                        AND t.SalesType IN (8, 9, 10, 12, 13, 14)
                        ORDER BY t.calltime)
                THEN 'Not Missed'

                --Anything that I missed
                ELSE 'ERR'  
            END

    END

RETURN @Status
```

Here is the view that I wrote to replace the mess above:

```
---- Main Data

    WITH a AS (SELECT t.SalesDate, t.CallNumber, t.SalesNumber, cr.descr AS CancelReason, t.SaleMade, f.MyDBSales_Person AS OFacAcctOwner, b2.SalesPersonNumber AS CSAcctOwner, cr.code AS CancelCode, ui.SalesPersonID AS SalesPersonThatMissed, tmt.misc15, t.calldate + ' ' + t.calltime AS CallDate,  t.SalesType,
        AccountOwner = 
            CASE
                WHEN t.SalesType IN (8, 12) THEN b.SalesPersonNumber
            WHEN t.SalesType IN (9, 10, 13, 14) AND LEN(f.MyDBSales_Person) < 2 THEN 'LF 0' + CAST(f.MyDBSales_Person AS nvarchar(1)) 
            WHEN t.SalesType IN (9, 10, 13, 14) AND LEN(f.MyDBSales_Person) >= 2 THEN 'LF ' + CAST(f.MyDBSales_Person AS nvarchar(2))
            END
        FROM  MyDB.dbo.Calls AS t 
        LEFT JOIN MyDB.dbo.Cancellation_Reasons AS cr ON t.CxlReason = cr.code
        LEFT JOIN MyDB.dbo.Vehicle_Schedule AS vs ON t.SchRecNo=vs.schrecno     
        LEFT JOIN MyDB.dbo.Customers AS f ON t.ofac = f.code
        LEFT JOIN MyDB.dbo.Call_Sources AS cs ON t.callsource = cs.code
        LEFT JOIN MyDB.dbo.SalesTypes AS p ON t.SalesType=p.code     
        LEFT JOIN MyDB.dbo.Trip_Misc_Times AS tmt ON t.job=tmt.job AND t.SalesDate=tmt.SalesDate     
        LEFT JOIN MyDB.dbo.SalesPerson_IDs AS ui ON vs.SalesPerson_code=ui.code    
        LEFT JOIN SalesPeople AS b On ui.SalesPersonID = b.SalesPersonNumber AND b.IsActive = 1
        LEFT JOIN AccountAssignment AS csa ON cs.code = csa.ZollCallSourceID
        LEFT JOIN SalesPeople AS b2 ON csa.AssignedSalesPersonID = b2.SalesPersonID
        WHERE t.SalesType IN (1, 2, 8, 9, 10, 12, 13, 14, 18) 
        AND t.SalesNumber>0 AND ui.SalesPersonID NOT LIKE 'LF 00%' AND ui.SalesPersonID NOT LIKE 'IAA%' ),

---- Checks Completed

b AS 
    (

SELECT t.CallNumber, t.SaleMade, t.SalesType, ui.SalesPersonID, t.SalesNumber, 
    t.calldate + ' ' + t.calltime AS CallDate 
    --CAST(t.calltime + ' ' + t.calldate AS datetime2(1)) AS CallDate 
    FROM MyDB.dbo.Calls AS t
    LEFT JOIN MyDB.dbo.Vehicle_Schedule AS vs ON t.SchRecNo=vs.schrecno     
    LEFT JOIN MyDB.dbo.SalesPerson_IDs AS ui ON vs.SalesPerson_code=ui.code    
    WHERE SalesType IN (8, 9, 10, 12, 13, 14) AND t.SaleMade=7
    AND t.SalesNumber>0 AND ui.SalesPersonID NOT LIKE 'LF 00%' AND ui.SalesPersonID NOT LIKE 'IAA%'),

---- Checks other Missed

c AS
    (

SELECT DISTINCT (c2.SalesNumber), c1.CallNumber, c2.SalesPersonID, c1.CallC1 AS CallDate--,  c2.CancelReason, c2.CancelCode 
    FROM
    (SELECT --TOP (1) --> top 1 retuns MORE rows, not less 
    MIN(t.calldate + ' ' + t.calltime) AS CallC1, t.CallNumber
    FROM MyDB.dbo.Calls AS t
    LEFT JOIN MyDB.dbo.Cancellation_Reasons AS cr ON t.CxlReason = cr.code
    LEFT JOIN MyDB.dbo.Vehicle_Schedule AS vs ON t.SchRecNo=vs.schrecno     
    LEFT JOIN MyDB.dbo.SalesPerson_IDs AS ui ON vs.SalesPerson_code=ui.code    
    WHERE SalesType IN (8, 9, 10, 12, 13, 14) AND t.SaleMade <> 7
    AND t.SalesNumber > 0 
    AND ui.SalesPersonID NOT LIKE 'LF 00%' 
    AND ui.SalesPersonID NOT LIKE 'IAA%'
    AND cr.code IN (14, 16, 17, 18, 19, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 30, 31, 38 , 40, 41, 42, 43, 45)
    GROUP BY t.CallNumber)
    AS c1
    JOIN 
    (SELECT t.CallNumber, t.SaleMade, t.SalesType, ui.SalesPersonID, t.SalesNumber, 
    t.calldate + ' ' + t.calltime AS CallDate, cr.descr AS CancelReason, cr.code AS CancelCode
    FROM MyDB.dbo.Calls AS t
    LEFT JOIN MyDB.dbo.Cancellation_Reasons AS cr ON t.CxlReason = cr.code
    LEFT JOIN MyDB.dbo.Vehicle_Schedule AS vs ON t.SchRecNo=vs.schrecno     
    LEFT JOIN MyDB.dbo.SalesPerson_IDs AS ui ON vs.SalesPerson_code=ui.code    
    WHERE SalesType IN (8, 9, 10, 12, 13, 14) AND t.SaleMade <> 7
    AND t.SalesNumber>0 AND ui.SalesPersonID NOT LIKE 'LF 00%' AND ui.SalesPersonID NOT LIKE 'IAA%'
    AND cr.code IN (14, 16, 17, 18, 19, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 30, 31, 38 , 40, 41, 42, 43, 45)
    ) 
    AS c2
    ON c1.CallNumber = c2.CallNumber AND c1.CallC1 = c2.CallDate),

----Checks Cancelled

d AS 
    (

SELECT  t.CallNumber, t.SaleMade, t.SalesType, ui.SalesPersonID, t.SalesNumber, 
    t.calldate + ' ' + t.calltime AS CallDate, cr.descr AS CancelReason, cr.code AS CancelCode
    FROM MyDB.dbo.Calls AS t
    LEFT JOIN MyDB.dbo.Cancellation_Reasons AS cr ON t.CxlReason = cr.code
    LEFT JOIN MyDB.dbo.Vehicle_Schedule AS vs ON t.SchRecNo=vs.schrecno     
    LEFT JOIN MyDB.dbo.SalesPerson_IDs AS ui ON vs.SalesPerson_code=ui.code    
    WHERE SalesType IN (8, 9, 10, 12, 13, 14) AND t.SaleMade <> 7
    AND t.SalesNumber>0 AND ui.SalesPersonID NOT LIKE 'LF 00%' AND ui.SalesPersonID NOT LIKE 'IAA%' 
    AND cr.code IN (3, 6, 7, 8, 13, 27, 32, 33, 36, 37, 46))



SELECT DISTINCT(a.SalesDate), a.SalesNumber, a.accountowner,
    TransportStatus = 
        CASE
            WHEN a.SaleMade = 7 THEN 'Completed'
            WHEN a.CancelReason = '<NONE>' THEN 'Completed'
            WHEN a.CancelCode IN (3, 6, 7, 8, 13, 27, 32, 33, 36, 37, 46) 
                THEN 'Cancelled'
            WHEN a.CancelCode IN (-1, 1, 2, 4, 5, 9, 10, 11, 12, 15, 20, 26, 28, 29, 34, 35, 39, 44) 
                THEN 'Ignore'
            WHEN b.SalesNumber IS NOT NULL 
                AND a.SalesType IN (8, 9, 10, 12, 13, 14) THEN 'Saved by ' + b.SalesPersonID
            WHEN a.misc15 IS NOT NULL THEN 'Not Missed'
            WHEN a.SalesType IN (1, 2, 18) AND (a.SaleMade <> 7 OR a.CancelReason <> '<None>')
                THEN '(Missed) ' + a.CancelReason
            WHEN d.SalesNumber IS NOT NULL THEN 'Not Missed'
            WHEN c.SalesNumber <> a.SalesNumber AND c.SalesPersonID = a.AccountOwner THEN 'Not Missed'
            WHEN c.SalesNumber <> a.SalesNumber AND a.SalesPersonThatMissed <> a.AccountOwner  THEN 'Not Missed'    
            WHEN a.SalesPersonThatMissed = a.AccountOwner THEN '(Missed) ' + a.CancelReason
            WHEN c.SalesNumber = a.SalesNumber THEN '(Missed) ' + a.CancelReason
            WHEN c.SalesNumber IS NULL AND b.SalesNumber IS NULL AND d.SalesNumber IS NULL 
                THEN '(Missed) ' + a.CancelReason
            ELSE  'Err' 
        END

FROM 
    a
    LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    b ON a.CallNumber = b.CallNumber
    LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    c ON a.CallNumber = c.CallNumber 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    d ON a.CallNumber = d.CallNumber

    WHERE SalesDate >= '2012-01-01'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out.

I had not considered all the possible permutations of the problem, as such, the view was not handling the business rules as it should have.

I ended up adding another CTE (although, I'm not entirely sure that these count as CTEs) and further logic to the Case statement at the very end.